# Array como un parámetro en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

En mi función de **Ajax**, al finalizar la consulta ejecuto la  función **success**, que tiene como único parámetro, **response** y dentro tiene el **Array** que contiene las posibles respuestas de la consulta y sus respectivas instrucciones, para todos los strings, tiene por defecto hacer un **alert()**.

```
    success: function response(response){
        1 = window.location.href = "client",
        ERR_WRONG = "Wrong pass",
        ERR_UNREG = "Create Account",
        ERR_SERV = "Try again :(",
        unknown = "Unknown error"
    }
```

Éstas instrucciones las voy a utilizar en todas las consultas **Ajax**, así que decidí hacer una función para ahorrar más líneas, pero la función no reconoce el **Array** (así que omite todo). Poner el Array de Objetos como parámetro dentro de la función me dió error.

```
success: function response({ERR_WRONG: "uwu", ERR_UNREG: "owo"})
```

Comment: Hola Esteban, he intentado entender lo que quieres hacer sin mucho éxito.
¿Podrías explicarlo de una forma más clara y con un ejemplo claro?

Answer (score 0):

Para declarar una objeto de tipo Array usando literales, los miembros se ponen entre corchetes `[]` no entre llaves `{}`.

Ejemplo

```
var frutas = ['manzana','naranja'];
```

En la primer código la función response usa su propio nombre como argumento, lo cual no aparentemente no ayuda en nada en este caso. Además, la función incluye la declaración de variables globales siendo la primera asignar un objeto a un literal de tipo número, lo cual me parece que tampoco ayuda en nada.

La segunda función response tiene como argumento un objeto "general" no uno de tipo Array.

Referencia:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array